# Join POSIX path on Windows

Tags: java, path

I am on a Windows machine and need to communicate with some paths to a `POSIX` system. I would, therefore, like to join two `POSIX` paths on Windows. In Python, I would be able to use the `posixpath` standard library to do this, even on Windows, but it seems Java's `Path` class only supports installed file systems - of which `POSIX` is not one on a Windows machine.

Currently, I am using this:

```
private String posixJoin(String a, String b) {
    StringBuilder joined = new StringBuilder(a);

    if (!a.endsWith("/") && !a.isEmpty()) {
        joined.append('/');
    }

    joined.append(b);

    return joined.toString();
}
```

But I am wary of any edge cases there might be in dealing with paths and would rather like to use something from the standard library if possible. Is there anything in the Java standard library or ecosystem for joining paths other than the ones found on the current machine?

Comment: why are you couldn't work with `Path` and at the end make `Path.toString().replace('\\', '/')`? Yes, you don't want to use external libraries, but [FilenameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) could resolve problem with this one

Comment: @ZhenyaM A possible solution, but still seems less than ideal and it's unclear to me if there are any edge cases for that. I wrote Windows in the title, but ideally I would not like to assume it running on Windows either.

Comment: Ok, you could use `FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(path.toString())`